# How do you use insert() in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, insert

```
myList = ["l","r","e"]
myList.insert("x")
```

I know that when using insert you need two arguments ,but
what is the second argument I should pass?

Comment: Is there a way i can choose where to add a item in a certain spot on a list using append()?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also if you want to add more information to your question, you can edit the question.  You should not leave more information as a comment.

Comment: First check the method docs `>>> help(list.index)` if that isn't detailed enough then check [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). If you still need clarification then search around before coming here to post a question.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is the position to insert the element. The second argument is the element.

```
>>> myList = ["l", "r", "e"]
>>> myList.insert(0, "a")
['a', 'l', 'r', 'e']
```